# How to calculate ego-motion using cv.recoverPose()?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Recently I used `findEssentialMat` and `recoverPose` to get the rotation angles (pitch, yaw, roll) of a camera given two frames. I noticed that `recoverPose` actually gives a counter-intuitive result, since it calculates the direction that points move instead of the camera, see [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/31421/opencv-3-essentialmatrix-and-recoverpose/).

Based on the explanation of the link, I could get the "correct" answer by simply **inverting** the R matrix, i.e. R^(-1). However, as I use these two simple images for testing, the results in `euler angle` are:

```
[ 1.19186314e+02 -3.94661600e-02 -1.79903575e+02]  # from inverted R
[ 1.19186327e+02 -6.49371021e-02 -1.79918523e+02]  # from original R
```

both are wrong (wether I inverted or not), since I merely **rotate** the camera upward (rotation around x-axis).

The images I used are:[image: first] and [image: second]

Below is my complete code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# invert the original R from direct output of Essential matrix 
def invert_R(R_mat):
    R_mat_inv = R.from_matrix(R_mat).inv()
    return R_mat_inv.as_euler('zyx', degrees=True)


# testing code
img1 = cv.imread('img/5.jpg') #self-defined
img2 = cv.imread('img/6.jpg')

# use ORB detector to do feature matching
orb = cv.ORB_create()
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# extract coordinates of matched keypoints
kpts1 = np.array([kp1[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches], dtype=np.int)
kpts2 = np.array([kp2[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches], dtype=np.int)
img3 = cv.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10],None,flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

# calculate Essential, get Roation matrix
E, mask = cv.findEssentialMat(kpts1, kpts2, prob=0.9999, threshold=0.1)
_, R_est, t_est, mask_pose = cv.recoverPose(E, kpts1, kpts2)


# calculate inverted R and origianl R matrix, both displayed in euler angles.
R1_ang = invert_R(R_est)
R2_ang = R.from_matrix(R_est).as_euler('zyx', degrees=True)
print(R1_ang)
print(R2_ang)
plt.imshow(img3), plt.show()
```

Comment: is your image undistorted? Did you check whether the matches and the keypoints are good?

Comment: you could try cv::decomposeHomographyMat too

Comment: i guess there might not ge enough matchable keypoints in the upper half of the image...